# Get the number of users for each role

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm using the default .NET Membership Provider and filling a Gridview with roles, using Roles.GetAllRoles(). I have a commandfield to delete roles and a boundfield for the role itself. What I need to do is to add the number of users per role, the role column would look like this;

Administrators(4)
Supervisors(12)

To prevent deleting a role that has users, I was thinking of using the RowCreated event to fetch the database and add the value to the roles. Is there a better way to do it?

Edit: Solution
To achieve what I need I had to use RowDataBound event.

```
protected void RoleList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string roleName = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("RoleNameLabel")).Text;

            if (roleName.Trim().Length > 0 && Roles.RoleExists(roleName))
            {
                Int32 roleCount = Roles.GetUsersInRole(roleName).Count();
                ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("RoleNameLabel")).Text += "(" + roleCount + ")";
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Roles.GetUsersInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=IT-IT&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.SECURITY.ROLES.GETUSERSINROLE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true). For example:

```
If Roles.GetUsersInRole(strRole).Count > 0 Then
    'do NOT delete this role
End If
```

Comment: Thank you tezzo, that make my day :)